# ¿Cómo ordernar una lista creada por el usuario?

Tags: python, algoritmos, ordenamiento

Tengo que preguntarle al usuario hasta 10 números diferentes y crear un programa que los resuelva numéricamente.

Hasta ahora, he podido realizar el método burbuja para resolver listas, sin preguntarle al usuario, pero no puedo conectar el método burbuja con los números que ponga el usuario.

Les proporcionaré un ejemplo:

Preguntar al usuario "pon un numero".

```
3
12
10
14
```

Resultado:

```
4 números fueron escritos
3,10,12,14
```

Comment: Hola Microplo, es recomendable tomarse un tiempo en redactar correctamente la pregunta, explicando claramente que se quiere conseguir y cuidando el lenguaje y la ortografía. Por otro lado, incluye siempre el código que lleves hecho en la pregunta. Yo he entendido que deseas que el usuario ingrese un número indeterminado de enteros separados por un espacio e introducirlos en una lista para poder pasarselos a tu función de ordenamiento, ¿es correcto?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma , Solicitar el Número como mencionas , luego hacer un `split` de tu `String` ingresado , esto retornará una `lista` que será asignado a la variable `lista` , luego mediante la función [len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) sabremos cuantos elementos hay en la lista, para luego concatenar el mensaje final ("Como el ejemplo que expusiste en la Pregunta") , `join` para convertir la lista a `String` donde entre las `''` irá el caracter que separará los elementos.

```
lista = []
text = input("Ingrese Numero ")
lista = [int(i) for i in text.split(' ')]#Convert lista de Int
lista.sort()#Ordenar la Lista
print(len(lista) , " Números Fueron Escritos " , ','.join(str(v) for v in lista))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://repl.it/EIWN/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

En Python existe la función `sort()` la cual te ordena de menor a mayor el contenido de un arreglo. Con esto ya solo necesitas agregar a un arreglo todo lo ingresado por el usuario y después aplicar el método.

Espero te sirva este ejemplo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
num = []  # Contendrá los numeros

print("Ingresa 3 Numeros")
for x in range(3):
    ingresado = input("Ingrese:")  # Capturamos lo ingresado por teclado
    num.append(ingresado)  # Agregamos al arreglo lo ingresado

num.sort() #Ordenamos el arreglo
print("De menor a mayor sus numeros ingresados")
print(num)  # Mostramos
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te sirva:

```
print("Ingresa numeros, 0 para terminar")
lista = []
num = input()
while num != 0:
    lista.append(num)
    num = input()

print("%d numeros fueron escritos") % len(lista)
print(sorted(lista))
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Siempre es interesante [edit] la respuesta incluyendo algún tipo de explicación.